# Why does unhboxing seem to ignore vertical mode and why does unvboxing seem to ignore horizontal mode?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, primitives

**First question**

Why does unhboxing seem to ignore vertical mode and why does unvboxing seem to ignore horizontal mode?

The MWE after the next two pictures

- both delivers the text of the first question
- and illustrates the effects of `\unhbox`/`\unhcopy` in vertical mode and of `\unvbox`/`\unvcopy` in horizontal mode.

The text of the first question also is in the next two pictures. They are the result of compiling the MWE.

[image]

[image]

```
\newbox\MyBox

\setbox\MyBox=\hbox{%
                      \vbox{\hbox{box1a}\hbox{box1b}}%
                      \vbox{\hbox{box2a}\hbox{box2b}}%
                      \vbox{\hbox{box3a}\hbox{box3b}}%
                    }

\noindent{%
\bf The {\tt\string\hbox} in box-register {\tt\string\MyBox} is:\hfill\break
\tt\string\hbox\string{\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ %
\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box1a\string}\string\hbox\string{box1b\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ %
\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box2a\string}\string\hbox\string{box2b\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ %
\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box3a\string}\string\hbox\string{box3b\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ %
\string}\char37 \hfill
}%

\noindent{\bf In vertical mode I expect boxes to be placed atop/below each 
other no matter if the boxes to be placed themselves are horizontal or vertical 
boxes.\hfill\break
Thus in vertical mode I expect from {\tt\string\unhcopy}ing the {\tt\string\hbox} held in
box-register {\tt\string\MyBbox} that the three {\tt\string\vbox}es it contains are 
placed atop/below each other:}\bigskip

\par\vbox{\hbox{box1a}\hbox{box1b}}%
    \vbox{\hbox{box2a}\hbox{box2b}}%
    \vbox{\hbox{box3a}\hbox{box3b}}%

\bigskip\noindent{\bf But in vertical mode from {\tt\string\unhcopy}ing  I
get the three vertical boxes placed to the left/right of each other, with {\tt\string\parindent}-glue
at the left of the leftmost box:}\bigskip

\par\unhcopy\MyBox

\bigskip\noindent{\bf Just as if I did {\tt\string\box} the {\tt\string\hbox}
in horizontal mode:}\bigskip

\par\leavevmode\box\MyBox

\bigskip\noindent{\bf Why? Where am I wrong in my understanding of the workings of {\tt\string\unhbox}/{\tt\string\unhcopy}?}

\vfill\eject

\setbox\MyBox=\vbox{%
                \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box1a}\hbox{box1b}}}%
                \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box2a}\hbox{box2b}}}%
                \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box3a}\hbox{box3b}}}%
              }

\bigskip\noindent{\bf
\bf The {\tt\string\vbox} in box-register {\tt\string\MyBox} is:\hfill\break
\tt
\string\vbox\string{\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \string\hbox\string{\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box1a\string}%
\string\hbox\string{box1b\string}\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \string\hbox\string{\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box2a\string}%
\string\hbox\string{box2b\string}\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \string\hbox\string{\string\vbox\string{\string\hbox\string{box3a\string}%
\string\hbox\string{box3b\string}\string}\string}\char37 \hfill\break
\null\ \ \ \ \ \string}\char37 \hfill
}%

\noindent{\bf In horizontal mode I expect boxes to be placed left/right to each other no 
matter if the boxes to be placed themselves are horizontal or vertical boxes.\hfill\break
Thus in horizontal mode I expect from {\tt\string\unvcopy}ing the {\tt\string\vbox} held in
box-register {\tt\string\MyBbox} that the three {\tt\string\hbox}es it contains are placed
left/right to each other, with {\tt\string\parindent}-glue at the left of the leftmost
{\tt\string\hbox}:}\bigskip

\leavevmode\hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box1a}\hbox{box1b}}}%
           \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box2a}\hbox{box2b}}}%
           \hbox{\vbox{\hbox{box3a}\hbox{box3b}}}%

\bigskip\noindent{\bf But in horizontal mode from {\tt\string\unvcopy}ing 
I get the three horizontal boxes placed atop/below each other:}\bigskip

\leavevmode\unvcopy\MyBox

\bigskip\noindent{\bf Just as if I did {\tt\string\box} the {\tt\string\vbox} in vertical mode:}\bigskip

\par\box\MyBox

\bigskip\noindent{\bf Why? Where am I wrong in my understanding of the workings of {\tt\string\unvbox}/{\tt\string\unvcopy}?}

\bye
```

---

---

**Second question:**

Assume a box-register `\MyBox` holding a `\vbox` which in turn contains many lines/many `\hboxes` of equal length.

`\box`ing that box register yields a vertical box whose single lines won't be split across pages:

```
\newcount\tmpcnt
\newbox\MyBox
\setbox\MyBox=\vbox{%
  \tmpcnt=0 %
  \loop\advance\tmpcnt by 1 \hbox to 3cm{Line:\hfill\number\tmpcnt.}\ifnum\tmpcnt<100 \repeat
}%
\noindent
\box\MyBox
\bye
```

[image]

When `\unvbox`ing that box-register, then the single lines will be split across pages:

```
\newcount\tmpcnt
\newbox\MyBox
\setbox\MyBox=\vbox{%
  \tmpcnt=0 %
  \loop\advance\tmpcnt by 1 \hbox to 3cm{Line:\hfill\number\tmpcnt.}\ifnum\tmpcnt<100 \repeat
}%
\noindent
\nobreak\unvbox\MyBox
\bye
```

[image]

[image]

How can you achieve in combination with `\unvbox` that these lines will not only be split across pages but will also be flushed to the right? As if you did:

```
\newcount\tmpcnt
\tmpcnt=0 %
\noindent
\loop
\advance\tmpcnt by 1 %
\null\hfill\hbox to 3cm{Line:\hfill\number\tmpcnt.}\break
\ifnum\tmpcnt<100 \repeat
\par
\bye
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\unhbox` exposes a horizontal list so starts a new paragraph and new horizontal list just as a letter would do,  the common`\leavevmode`  is just `\def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}`

Comment: So `\unhbox` can only be used for re-processing a horizontal list (that probably was produced in restricted horizontal mode) in (non-restricted) horizontal mode? And `\unvbox` can only be used for re-processing a vertical list (that probably was produced in restricted vertical mode) in non-restricted vertical mode? So after `\unhbox` TeX is always in some horizontal mode and after `\unvbox` TeX is always in some vertical mode?

Comment: The TeXbook is not really clear in this point: It says in chapter 15, somewhere before exercise 15.10: `.... Similarly, \unvbox unwraps a vbox.`  I din't get what "unwrap" means in this context: After unwrapping a hbox you still have the horizontal list? After unwrapping a vbox you still have the vertical list? Not a sequence of single boxes that before unwrapping were contained in the unwrapped box and after unwrapping can be re-processed in whatsoever mode?

Comment: Can you enter vertical-mode analogously by `\unvbox\voidb@x` delivering an empty vertical list where items/boxes can be appended vertically?

Comment: @MarsupialWallaby yes unboxing just adds the list in the box to the list being constructed, after making sure you are in the right sort of list.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. From what I read in the TeXbook ("unwrap a box") I concluded that after unboxing/after unwrapping a box the single boxes that were contained in that unwrapped box are available for re-processig in whatever mode TeX is at the time of unboxing/unwrapping. But this is not the case: the horizontal or vertical orientation of the list is maintained, so it is only possible to have glue recalculated between the list items? Would this be a reasonably coherent description of the concept?

Comment: you can reprocess the boxes in the list (sometimes) by working backwards with `\lastbox`, `\unskip` and friends.